# IE does not read properly my CSS - can not center content nor place my footer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am creating a simple homepage using HTML and CSS.

For my middle content, I use a `MainWrapper` class of a 1000px wide so everything is center but it seem that IE does not read it properly. I've been going through my code on and on, and everything seems fine.

Also, I am trying to bottom-fix my footer (position absolute), and IE does not show it either. But it shows my header that is also fixed by position absolute.

Comment: Which version of IE are you using? and please post some sample code too so we can figure out what's wrong =)

Comment: Sample code please... people tend to skip questions that dont include the effort on the assumption that the OP has not put in the effort to try and solve the issue before posting it here.

Comment: While IE certainly has its share of compatibility issues, a simple centered div is not one of them.. that tells me you are doing something very wrong.  Post some code, preferably use jsfiddle

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Code snippets are preferable than external jsfiddle.

Comment: If this is your full html, then you're missing a lot of stuff.. like html tags, head tags, a doctype tag.. this puts the browser into "quirks" mode in many browsers which renders in non-standard ways.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as this:

```
.mainWrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto; //Center the div
}
```

If this isn't what you want, please clearify your question and post some code of what you already have.

And for your footer dilemma:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bare-bones starting point for the page you described: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/f9rmjjum/)

Using `margin: 0 auto;` centers your content container nicely

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>

.header, .footer {
    width: 1000px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.main {
    width: 100px; 
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is the html (CSS lower)

<body>
   <header>
        <nav class="top_bottom">
            <!--MENU<ul>
               <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                </ul>-->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="MainWrapper">
        <img class="main_logo" src="images/logo_1000x400.jpg" title="Logo Mangeons Maison" alt="Logo Mangeons Maison"/>
        <div class="top_box">
        <p class="msg_const">Notre site Web est présentement en construction pour mieux répondre à vos attentes. Un menu détaillé ainsi qu’un bon de commande seront bientôt disponibles. Pour le moment, vous pouvez nous faire parvenir votre courriel pour recevoir notre menu hebdomadaire et par la suite vous pourrez commander via courriel. Écrivez-nous ou téléphonez-nous et il nous fera plaisir de vous répondre dans les plus brefs délais. </p>
        <a class="email" href="mailto:#">#</a>
        <p class="msg_const2">514-555-5555</p>
        <p class="msg_const1">Merci!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
   <footer class="footer">
     <div>
        <p></p>
     </div>
    </footer>
</body>

    CSS:
    .MainWrapper{
        width:1000px !important;
        margin:0 auto !important;
    }

    footer{
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
       width:100%;
       height:40px;  
       background:#E73E29;
    }
```

Comment: Edit your answer to include additional information, don't add it as an answer.  Answers are only for answers that answer the question.  Apparently moderators are too {redacted} to notice this though, since I flagged this as not an answer and they disputed it....